# Define time steps of tensorboardX

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, pytorch, tensorboardx

I am using tensorboardX(2.6) with pytorch, I also have tensorflow-gpu(2.10.0)installed.

Now my tensorboard can only show 10 time intervals(like 100\200\300...1000 if there're 1000 steps in total) in time seires\images interface, but I want more time steps available.

Is there any way to do this? I cannot find self-defining option. Thanks for your time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy0er.png)

Is there any way to do this? I cannot find self-defining option. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I save scalars for each step, I want to view my scalar for each step, but now I can only see 10steps(100\200\300\..1000).